# Push notification when app is killed by the user?

Tags: mobile-application, push-notification

My team is wanting to find a way to notify the user that when swiping up to kill our app, certain features/functionality will be compromised. We have thought about adding some information in the onboarding process to tell them up front and we have also seen the example from the Tesla app - when closed the app will send a push notification telling the user to keep the app running for the best experience. I have worked to find other examples of showing this information or push notification but have not really been able to find anything else.

I am kind of just leaning towards recommending not doing a notification or mentioning anything about it in the app, hoping a user would understand that killing an app would affect the performance. But wouldn't be opposed to the push notification if it really was beneficial and not annoying to an user.

Has anyone else run into this with their team? How should I proceed with this one?

Comment: Most of the time, users kill an app when something went wrong and they need to get unstuck. How criticial is it to interfere with their attempt to reset the app? Will they be in danger? Lose all their data?

Comment: @Izquierdo I definitely need to ask about those specifics - what would be detrimental when the app is closed. But our app does connect to a hearing device where the app enhances functionality and hearing quality, so I can see how the devs/product leads would want to encourage users to not kill the app.

Answer (score 0):

Because your users are performing an action that could have potentially dangerous consequences, waiting until the app is closed and sending a push notification might be too late. I think, if possible, you need two steps:

1. When the user performs the gesture to kill the app, ask for confirmation. I don't know if this is technically possible, though it's a pattern we see in operating systems and web pages. You could quickly warn that hearing loss might occur if the app is closed.

[image: Confirm restart modal from Apple]

[image: Navigate away modal]

2. Send a push immediately after the app closes with a notice. "[App] is no longer running. This may affect your hearing." And then show a button that allows them to re-open the app. This also follows patterns that are used in system notification designs.

[image: Unexpectedly quit notification from Safari]